# Rails 5, javascript is not loaded in production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

In my app I use the bootstrap theme (gentelella), and in one of my pages I have a Moris graph which works perfect in Development evniroment but in production(heroku) doesn't work.

The error in the console is the following: 
**Uncaught ReferenceError: Morris is not defined
**

It looks like the js for the Moris graph(the script is included in gentelella) is not loaded but everything else works fine.

Code for my graph:

```
   <div id="graph_line"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   new Morris.Line({
      element: 'graph_line',
      data: [
      {Date: 'mydate1', y: myvalue1},
      {Date: 'mydate2', y: myvalue2},
      {Date: 'mydate3', y: myvalue3}
      ],
      xkey: 'Date',
      ykeys: ['y'],
      labels: ['Y'],
      hideHover: 'auto',
      lineColors: ['#26B99A', '#34495E', '#ACADAC', '#3498DB'],
      resize: true
    });
   </script>
```

I don't include any Moris.js  because it is already included in my theme.

I don't understand why it works fine in local and not in production.

After some researching, I added this line in my production.rb:

```
 config.assets.debug = true
```

and in heroku logs I have the error:

**The asset "application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline**
and the app is not running but it runs without the above line.

Any idea why my graph is not working in production and why heroku does not see my application.css

**P.S** in my assets I have application.scss and not application.css could this cause the problem? But I need the file to be .scss

My application.js:

```
   //= require jquery
   //= require jquery.turbolinks
   //= require jquery_ujs
   //= require jquery.remotipart
   //= require pnotify
   //= require unobtrusive_flash
   //= require flashes
   //= require gentelella
   //= require gentelella-custom
   //= require_tree .
```

The morris scripts are initialized in the gentellela-custom.js (**init_morris_charts();**)

And my application.html.erb

```
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Comment: You need to show more of the source code. You're only showing where you make the actual call to `Morris` when we need to see where you're including/importing `Morris`, your views/partials, `application.js`, and so on.

Comment: Sure, I'll update my question.

Comment: Search for `Morris` inside the assets that are being loaded. That will help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

Update you code to have a debugger reference:
`<%= debugger; %>` before the line with: `new Morris.Line({`, and then open your favorite browser, switch to the debugger window and you will have a break point in there.
That will help you see if Morris is loaded at that point in time.